# Finding $J^{PC}$ for multiparticle final state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, angular-momentum, standard-model, parity

Funnily enough, I have a question about an assertion made in one of [my own papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10632) (it was made by one of my collaborators, not me).

---

At the bottom of pg. 8 it is stated that

> ... [T]he final state necessarily has $J^{PC}=1^{--}$... As a result, the only final states which we need consider are $\pi^{+} \pi^{-}, K^{+} K^{-}, K^{L} K^{S}, \rho \pi, \text { and } \omega \pi^{0}$.

So it looks like he's saying that the $J^{PC}$ of the $\pi^+ \pi^-$ state is $1^{--}$, which doesn't make sense to me. If we define

\begin{align}
\mathbf{J = J_+ + J_-}
\end{align}

and I just act on the state i get $\mathbf{J}(\pi^+ \pi^-) = 0$, since each pion has net momentum of $0$. In particular, they have $J^{PC}=0^-$.

So this leads me to my question: what is meant by the $J^{PC}$ of a multi-particle final state of mesons, and how do I calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Caramba!, how does one avoid the smear of "know-it-all" in explaining a paper to its author?]

I'm leaving isospin and such considerations aside, and wonder how a
$J^{PC}=1^{--}$ state (like the $\rho^0$, except heavier!) can decay into $\pi^+\pi^-$ (but *not* $\pi^0\pi^0$).

The charged π has $0^-$, and is not an eigenstate of C;  whereas  the neutral  π has $O^{-^+}$, which excludes the two neutral  π  decay by C.

So, how do you preserve spin? By unit orbital angular momentum, a P-wave decay, which  contributes negative parity, and, indeed, the  $\pi^+\pi^-$ combination has negative C. So, the angular momentum
is J=0+1+0=1, and the parity is - - -=-, in answer to your question.

The η counts as a neutral π here, except for isospin, so  the ηπ mode is also excluded by C as above, etc.

The ρπ (or ωπ) mode is allowed,  also for a P-wave, orbital angular momentum 1,  combining  $1^{--}$ with $1^{-}$ and $0^{-+}$ summing up to a $1^{--}$ for multiplicative P and Cs. The orbital angular momentum does not affect C.

Comment: Thanks. So if im understanding right, the reason why $C$ of $\pi^+ \pi^-$ odd is because swapping them does nothing and then we get an overall factor of $(-1)^{L + S}=(-1)^{1+0} = -1$

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_parity#Multiparticle_systems). The P wave antisymmetrizes them.